# telegram "webview", don`t work keyboard after open other chat and click arrow came back to "webview"

Tags: keyboard, telegram

Good day! We have a telegram webapp with urls to telegram users. By this urls we can transition to chat with user.
After, if we click button back(at the telegram chat), we are returning to the webapp.But after, if
we are going through the parts of webapp and click to the text inputs, keyboard don't activate.
We don't have a focus to the form inputs.
I am waiting for your thinks

If I using debug, I can see that event click is working, focus event also,
but keyboard whatever inactive.